# How to pass special characters to xml file

Tags: php, simplexml

I am editing a xml file a particular node file after tha I am saving tha but it contains some special character because of  **line number 7** of my code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');
$i=2;

foreach($xml->Page as $myPage){
if($myPage['id']==$i) {
    $da = "data";
    $text = "helloworld";
    $myPage->$da ="<![CDATA[{$text}]]>"; //line number 
    $xml->asXML('demo.xml');
}
```

how can I put the string as it is in xml file?

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML does not handle CDATA very well. If you want to write CDATA you need to use the [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) objects. For example:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('demo.xml');
$i = 2;

foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('Page') as $page) {
    if ($page->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value == $i) {
        $da = 'data';
        $text = 'helloworld';

        $data = $xml->createElement($da);
        $data->appendChild($xml->createCDATASection($text));

        $page->appendChild($data);
    }
}
```

If you want to continue to use SimpleXML, you can load just the element you want to write the CDATA into as a DOM object.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');
$i = 2;

foreach ($xml->Page as $page) {
    if ($page['id'] == $i) {
        $da = 'data';
        $text = 'helloworld';
        $page->$da = '';

        $node = dom_import_simplexml($page->$da);
        $dom = $node->ownerDocument;
        $node->appendChild($dom->createCDATASection($text));
    }
}

$xml->asXML('demo.xml');
```

Comment: No, i appled that but didn't worked for that's why i didn't accepted

Comment: @skumar Could you provide some insight on what did not work? If you could provide some more details, perhaps I could clean up my answer to resolve your issues.